# CSS look varies as browser change

Tags: html, css

CSS for my button is:

```
.custom-input-button {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 64.4%;
  top: 12.3%;
}
```

and rate box:

```
.rating-input {
  font-size: 25px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  left: 35%;
}
```

But bot button and Rate me option appears at varying position in Firefox and chrome.

More as Firefox version change position get affected. On my Firefox 23.0 it looks ok,
but in my friend PC FF version is different and position of button and Rate me option changes.

Comment: Might not be redered correctly!

Comment: Why you use   float right and left:35%; at the same time??

Answer (score 0):

inHm, try using

```
.rating-input {
                                font-size: 25px;
                                position:relative;
                                left:35%;
                        }
```

Without float left, because then you using such combinations some browsers can set it incorrectly.

The problem is that you use % to set a distance. Different browsers use percentages differently. Try to do it using px.

Comment: issue is with button class.

Comment: Write if it help for you